# How to preserve spaces in hyperlinks when converting restructured text to html?

Tags: restructuredtext, rst2html.py

I'm using python docutils and the rst2html.py script to convert restructured text to html.

I want to convert a line like this:

```
Test1 `(link1)  <C:/path with spaces/file.html>`_
```

Into something like this:

```
<p>Test1 <a class="reference external" href="C:/path with spaces/file.html">(link1)</a>
```

But instead I get this (spaces in path are dropped):

```
<p>Test1 <a class="reference external" href="C:/pathwithspaces/file.html">(link1)</a>
```

How do I preserve the whitespace in links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how you are grabbing the line from the file (or stdin), but you should convert the link related string to HTML entities. You can find more information in the following link [Escaping HTML - Python Wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/EscapingHtml).

Hope this help you.

Comment: I don't understand why I would what to do that in this case. I want my links to contain a space. I don't want a space to be replaced with a %20 because C:/path%20with%20spaces/file.html is not the same as C:/path with spaces/file.html. If I put C:/path%20with%20spaces/file.html into the windows explorer bar (not IE explorer) then it can't find the file.

Comment: even if you use file://c:\path%20with%20spaces\file.html in the link href?

Comment: @Mark humph, I thought it would work as it works for other environments like Dolphin (KDE) and Nautilus (Gnome). Good lucky.

Comment: @Mark: Try `file:///c:/path%20with%20spaces/file.htm` (all forward slashes; 3 of them before `c`).